# what is the difference of torch.nn.Softmax, torch.nn.funtional.softmax, torch.softmax and torch.nn.functional.log_softmax

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, softmax

I tried to find documents but cannot find anything about torch.softmax.

What is the difference among torch.nn.Softmax, torch.nn.funtional.softmax, torch.softmax and torch.nn.functional.log_softmax?

Examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

```
import torch

x = torch.rand(5)

x1 = torch.nn.Softmax()(x)
x2 = torch.nn.functional.softmax(x)
x3 = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x)

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(torch.log(x1))
print(x3)
```

```
tensor([0.2740, 0.1955, 0.1519, 0.1758, 0.2029])
tensor([0.2740, 0.1955, 0.1519, 0.1758, 0.2029])
tensor([-1.2946, -1.6323, -1.8847, -1.7386, -1.5952])
tensor([-1.2946, -1.6323, -1.8847, -1.7386, -1.5952])
```

`torch.nn.Softmax` and `torch.nn.functional.softmax` gives identical outputs, one is a class (pytorch module), another one is a function.
`log_softmax` applies log after applying softmax.

NLLLoss takes log-probabilities (log(softmax(x))) as input. So, you would need log_softmax for NLLLoss, log_softmax is numerically more stable, usually yields better results.

Answer (score 1):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_1 = nn.LazyLinear(128)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
        self.output_function = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x, softmax="module"):
        y = self.layer_1(x)
        y = self.activation(y)
        y = self.layer_2(y)
        if softmax == "module":
            return self.output_function(y)

        # OR
        if softmax == "torch":
            return torch.softmax(y, dim=1)

        # OR (deprecated)
        if softmax == "functional":
            return nn.functional.softmax(y, dim=1)

        # OR (careful, the reason why the log is there is to ensure
        # numerical stability so you should use torch.exp wisely)
        if softmax == "log":
            return torch.exp(torch.log_softmax(y, dim=1))

        raise ValueError(f"Unknown softmax type {softmax}")


x = torch.rand(2, 2)
net = Network()

for s in ["module", "torch", "log"]:
    print(net(x, softmax=s))
```

Basically `nn.Softmax()` creates a module, so it returns a *function* whereas the others are pure functions.

Why would you need a log softmax? Well an example lies in the docs of `nn.Softmax`:

> This module doesn't work directly with NLLLoss,
> which expects the Log to be computed between the Softmax and itself.
> Use `LogSoftmax` instead (it's faster and has better numerical properties).

See also [What is the difference between log_softmax and softmax?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-log-softmax-and-softmax/11801)